# JavaScript Constructor Function Methods

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why I need the `PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.slice` method below.

Why can't I just use `slice(3,6).join('')` inside my other methods without needing to add `PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.slice` method? When the interpreter doesn't find the method on the PhoneNumberFormatter object, wouldn't it just look up the prototype chain to find `slice` and join on the `Array` prototype?

```
function PhoneNumberFormatter(numbers) {
    this.numbers = numbers;
}

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.render = function() {
    var string = '';
    string += this.parenthesize(this.getAreaCode());
    string += ' ';
    string += this.getExchangeCode();
    string += '-';
    string += this.getLineNumber();
    return string;
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getAreaCode = function() {
    return this.slice(0, 3);
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getExchangeCode = function() {
    return this.slice(3, 6);
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getLineNumber = function() {
    return this.slice(6)
};

PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.parenthesize = function(string) {
    return '(' + string + ')';
};

// why do I need the following method?
PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.slice = function(start, end) {
    return this.numbers.slice(start, end).join('');
};

var phoneNumberOne = new PhoneNumberFormatter([6, 5, 0, 8, 3, 5, 9, 1, 7, 2]);

phoneNumberOne.render()
```

Comment: The only thing you are doing here is calling the slice method of the PhoneNumberFormatter and joining the results, it's not like you need it but it really makes your code look a lot cleaner and simpler, namely, you only need to do the joining once and refer to the numbers property in one place, from a do not copy yourself perspective, this is quite a good way to do it, I would say

Comment: What prototype chain are you thinking of that would lead to `Array.prototype`?

Comment: @melpomene He is rather referring to the `PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.slice` method ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was created to make the code cleaner and prevents code duplication.

As the use of the *slice* keyword in two different places seems to confuse you I'll explain briefly the differences.

In your prototype methods (e.g. getAreaCode, getExchangeCode, ...), the keyword *this* represents a PhoneNumberFormatter object. When you call `this.slice()` (in the methods), you are calling the *slice* method of this object hence the one created in your code.

But in your slice method (the one in your code), you are calling `this.numbers.slice()`. Here you call the slice method on an array (`this.numbers`). You are using the native array method *slice*.

You could write your methods like so and remove the slice method created in your code:

```
PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getAreaCode = function() {
    return this.numbers.slice(0, 3).join('');
};
```

Comment: Personally, I like the original code better, if something needs to be changed, you only need to change it at a single place

Comment: @Icepickle I do like it better too. OP just seemed unsure of the way he could write the methods differently so I cleared that out.

Comment: Though I understand your point, I think he means something else (nl: the sentence of the interpreter and the array prototype method), I think you should rather explain how the slice method is found back on `this`. I think part of the OP's confusion might be that `slice` name is used, and not, lets say `take` (just for not confusing the OP)

Comment: Nice update of your question :) I think you do a better way of explaining it than me :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I understand now.  Great explanation.

Comment: @kyle if the answer helped you, you  should mark it as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I think the main confusion you seem to have is the name of the method `slice`. This leads you to believe that it is the array method, but in fact it is not.

The `slice` method mentioned in your code is the `slice` method of the `PhoneNumberFormatter`, not the one of the array.

Because of this, the interpreter could never find the `slice` method in the prototype chain, because the prototype of the `PhoneNumberFormatter` would be `object`, and just calling slice would rather throw an error that the method is undefined.

The `this.slice` method refers to `PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.slice` and this one will refer to it's own `numbers` property and will then call the `slice` method on the `numbers` Array.

Maybe it is simply easier to rename the code like:

```js
function PhoneNumberFormatter( numberArr ) {
  this.numbers = numberArr.slice(); // copy numbers
}


PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.getAreaCode = function() {
    return this.take(0, 3);
};


PhoneNumberFormatter.prototype.take = function() {
  return Array.prototype.splice.apply( this.numbers, arguments ).join('');
};

var formatter = new PhoneNumberFormatter([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);

console.log(formatter.getAreaCode());
```

Which maybe makes it more clear to you, that the `take` method is simply a utility method simplifying your code, cause be honest, why would you want to repeat for 5 different methods the `slice` and `join` part, and then take a potential risk of copying an error 5 times, or in case you need to change something, need to make the same change 5 times